# Calculate power consumption to see if the node dies

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using Omnet++ and Inet 3.4.0 and I am trying to simulate power consumption and make the node dead after it's energy gets over. I tried IdealEnergySource model and SimpleEnergyStorage. but I could not figure out where to keep the parameter of the energy source. I tried in SimpleEnergyStorage.cc but could not find.

Than you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `Wireless08` tutorial from `INET` uses `IdealEnergyStorage` which has an **infinite** amount of energy. Therefore in that case a node will never be dead.
To model a real consumption one can use `SimpleEnergyStorage`. In `Wireless08` section of `omnetpp.ini` comment out the line:

```
#*.host*.energyStorageType = "IdealEnergyStorage"
```

and add the following lines:

```
**.host*.energyStorageType = "SimpleEnergyStorage"
**.host*.energyStorage.nominalCapacity = 0.10J
**.host*.energyStorage.initialCapacity = 0.09J
**.host*.energyStorage.nodeShutdownCapacity = 0J
**.host*.energyStorage.nodeStartCapacity = 0.01J
**.hasStatus = true
```

Moreover, edit `WirelessB.ned` and add at the beginning:

```
import inet.common.lifecycle.LifecycleController;
```

and in `submodules:`

```
lifecycleController: LifecycleController;
```

Comment: Yes I did Thank you!! 
 The main problem It shows that energy level is down but the node is not dead or it does not stop sending data. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Do you use an example of `INET` or an own model? If own one, could you edit your question and add content of `omnetpp.ini` as well as `NED` files of it?

Comment: I am using the tutorial provided in omnetpp.org.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now it contains an example of parameter's value for `SimpleEnergyStorage`.